# net_device and net_device_ops struct

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I would like add a new operation at the `struct net_device_ops` but I am a really newbye in this type of things and I am a bit worried to follow a wrong way from the begin.

I added a ops like this:

```
static const struct net_device_ops wl_netdev_ops =
{
/* The other operations..
.ndo_clear_stats = clear_stats
};
```

What is not clear from my point of view is how I can call from user space that, I usually take statisincs from

```
/sys/class/net/.../statistics
```

But now I really don't understand where my new operation is placed, can someone help me telling a good tutorial or link where I can find a simple example or tutorial ?

Thanks in advance,
pedr0

[Interesting material](http://forum.kernelnewbies.org/read.php?12,27482)

Answer (score 1):

You can't call it directly. You need to export its functionality somehow to userspace, e.g. via an ioctl, netlink, a procfs entry, etc. Which one of these is recommended depends largely on what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Usually it's also advised not to change core kernel structures like this, even if you don't plan to distribute your changes - sometimes order of kernel structure members or the size of it matters, and there are assumptions internally in the kernel regarding this. I'm pretty sure there is some other way to do what you want.